# OSP Control Automatic Logon Feature Fail

Tags: authentication, windows-xp, okuma

I have an Okuma OSP Machine Controller running Windows XP.

By default it attempts to automatically log on when the machine is turned on.
We have changed the default administrator password and now the auto-log on fails every time.

- How can I turn off this feature or update the password so that it succeeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Machine Types Effected*: Any machine with P200 or P300 control running Windows-XP

---

4/1/2014: **Confirmed the same applies to new OSP-300 Windows 7 controls**

---

2/1/2015: There is another (easier) way to accomplish this on Okuma controls.

This can be done using a utility in the TOOLS directory called the "Auto Logon Setting Tool". This is perfect for anyone uncomfortable with editing the registry.

#### Tool location:

[image: location]

#### The utility:

[image: utility]

Just choose the user you wish to to be logged on automatically, and click the "Register auto log-on" button.

---

This feature is enabled from the factory to allow users to get up and running quickly while still having the machine password protected. Because it is recommended to change the default password this is most likely a very common situation.

The automatic login behavior can be changed by editing registry settings.

- Click Start, type "regedit" (sans-quotes) in the run box, and press enter.
- In the folder structure in the left pane, navigate to the following folder:
  **>** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

**To turn the feature OFF**, change the key value of "AutoAdminLogon" to '0'

Similarly, the default user name and password can be changed by editing the appropriate keys to restore the functionality of the auto login feature.

Reference Microsoft Support article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231).

[image]